# Making values of functionals simultaneously positive

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

We work with real Banach spaces. Let $X$ be an infinite-dimensional Banach space and let $(f_n)$ be a sequence of norm-one functionals on $X$ that are linearly independent. Can we find an element $x\in X$ such that $f_n(x)>0$ for all $n$?

I guess not. What if $X$ is reflexive?

Comment: Let $F_{n}=\{ x : f_{n}(x) \le 0 \}$ for $n=1,2,3,\cdots$. Then $F_{n}$ is closed. You want to find $x \in X\setminus\bigcup_{n}F_{n}$ because that means $x \notin F_{n}$ for all $n$ and, hence, $f_{n}(x) > 0$ for all $n$. Have you thought about what happens if there is no such $x$?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/313425/a-certain-element-which-makes-functionals-positive